# Корректный путь к загруженному файлу

Tags: javascript, input, события

На сайте имеется возможность загрузить файл с помощью стандартной браузерной формы. Кнопка "Выберите файл".

```
<form class="file-form" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
        <input type="file" class="file-for-import" required="required" />
</form>
```

Обработка действий происходит с помощью фреймворка Marionette.

```
var MainImportView = Mn.LayoutView.extend({
    template: $(html)[0].outerHTML,
    ui: {
        file: '.file-for-import',
        generate: '.gen-tab',
        import: '.to-import'
    },
    events: {
        'click @ui.file': 'loadFile',
        // read content from file
        'click @ui.generate': 'readFields',
        'click @ui.import': 'import'
    },  
    loadFile: function(e) {
        var file = this.ui.file[0].value;
    },
    ...
});
```

И вот эта `file` определяется как **C:\fakepath\test.txt**, хотя выбранный файл test.txt находится в другой директории и вообще на диске D. Почему не загружается корректный путь?

Comment: Это не специфическая марионеттовская вещь, а ограничения на уровне браузера с целью безопасности.

Comment: @Утка Значит, для загрузки файла не нужно знать полный путь к нему?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как и сказал *@Утка*, стандартный путь **С:\fakepath** устанавливается многими браузерами, чтобы javascript сторонних сайтов не имел доступа к вашей файловой архитектуре. При этом загружается файл нормально. Вопрос решён.